# how to get the values of a checked checkbox and the output it on a input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, checkbox

I am trying to get the checked values of a checkbox and then display them in a field. I have two files the index which has the input field and then the checkbox is made in a modal which is a different component, the `selectlanguage`. I want that when a user checks one or more checkbox(es), the value(s) appears on the input and when unchecked, the value leaves the field.

Presently, what I am able to achieve is only a single value appearing on the input field.

Here is a snippet of the code.

index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SelectLanguage from "../../components/modal/selectLanguage";

const index = () => {
const [chosenLanguage, setChosenLanguage] = useState([]);

function checkLanguage(e) {
  setChosenLanguage(e.target.name);
};

<label className="relative block p-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 w-full" for="languages">
  <span for="languages">languages</span>
  <input
    id="languages"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Spanish, Arabic"
    autoComplete="off"
    onClick={languageShowModal}
    value={chosenLanguage}
  />
</label>
}

export default index;
```

selectlanguage.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function SelectLanguage({ open, handleClose, checkLanguage }) {
  const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    alert(e.target.name);
  };

  return open ? (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="spanish" onChange={checkLanguage} />
        <span>spanish</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="spanish" onChange={checkLanguage} />
        <span>french</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="spanish" onChange={checkLanguage} />
        <span>arabic</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  ) : (
    ""
  );
}
```

Comment: I think the way you call ```setChosenLanguage(e.target.name)``` is incorrect. You set it to an array initially, but then you just override it with a single value. You might want to add/remove the value to the array instead. ```setChosenLanguage([...chosenLanguage, e.target.name]);```

Comment: @szczocik, thanks for that, it works to an extent, but now, after I check a box, it adds it to the list and I uncheck it, it still adds it to the list. How can I only add the checked items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear to me how you have things hooked up, but a good strategy is to **reflect** the state of the DOM into your React state ([Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)), and then have a way of displaying that state. In your case, you want to store the state of a bunch of checkboxes, and one way to do this is with a map.

```js
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [ chosenLanguages, setChosenLanguages ] = useState({})

  const checkLanguage = (e) => {
    setChosenLanguages(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [e.target.value]: e.target.checked,
    }))
  }

  const showLanguages = () => {
    return Object.entries(chosenLanguages)
      .filter(([_, checked]) => checked)
      .map(([name, _]) => name)
      .join(', ')
  }

  return (
    <input value={showLanguages()} />
  )
}
```

Instead of an array, `chosenLanguages` is a map of language names to their checked state, for example:

```
{
  arabic: true,
  spanish: false,
  french: true,
}
```

When you've stored your state like this, you can transform it in whatever way you want when you render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using "e.target.value" didn't work as I was only getting "on" on the field, I had to change it to, "e.target.name" since I already had the name attribute on the different input tags. Was that a good way to go about it ?

Comment: Also, I would like to ask, I have the first value of the input tags to be checked by default, how can I ensure it is already listed on the field, or do I need to hard-code it in the "chosenLanguage" state.

Comment: Good questions, normally checkboxes that are related to each other have the same `name`, but different `value` which is why I used value here. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#handling_multiple_checkboxes

Comment: Regarding the second question, the link I provided on Controlled Components should provide a hint. Providing the default state to `chosenLanguage` is good practice, as long as you force the checkbox inputs to have its state also, for instance `checked={chosenLanguages.arabic}`.